# UDF - Return a table from a custom sql string execution with "Exec 'select * from ....' "

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, t-sql, user-defined-functions

How can I return a table from an UDF that executes a custom query string? Eg:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_AdvancedSearch
(

    @keywords varchar(255),
        (..... other params ....)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlQuery varchar(1000)
```

`.....

    SET @SqlQuery = 'my custom select  string previously generated'

EXEC(@SqlQuery)`

END

I was thinking maybe i could create a temp in memory table and then return it, but i don't want to allocate extra memory in the server for this purpose.

And...should i use a SP or an UDF to accomplished this goal? I have this running in a SP but the Linq2SQL cannot determine the return type and therefore i cannot use this function properly in my .NET code.

Thanks!
TT

Comment: How much data are you expecting to return in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erland has documented a lot of different ways to accomplish this (but not with functions, as someone else already pointed out), see: http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html ... may also require reading of his two dynamic SQL articles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you cannot use dynamic sql in a function.

Comment: Yes, this is true... will likely have to use a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs. Reading the article Aaron suggested helps to clarify. Greetings for all.